# Need help converting a .wav audio file to a .PNG , then back to the same .wav file

Tags: python, image, audio, encoding, compression

I am attempting to convert a sound file into an image, then back into that same sound file in Python. First, I'm reading the .wav with python's `wave` library, extract the frames, and then arrange the bytes as RGB tuples in a square image.

The output is cool and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwD75.png)

but when I try to convert the image back to a soundfile, the result is horrid. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here

```
import wave
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt


w = wave.open("sample.wav", mode = "rb")
frames = w.readframes(w.getnframes())
pixels = []

#####FRAMES CONVERTED TO PIXEL TUPLES######

for i in range(0,w.getnframes(),3):
    pixels.append((frames[i],frames[i+1],frames[i+2]))

#####FIT TO SQUARE IMAGE#####
dimensions = int(sqrt(w.getnframes()/3))

img = []

for x in range(0,dimensions):
    row = []
    for y in range(0,dimensions):
        row.append(pixels[x*dimensions+y])
    img.append(row)

array = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
new_image = Image.fromarray(array)
new_image.save('new.png')

p = Image.open("new.png",mode="r")
flatten = [x for sets in list(p.getdata()) for x in sets]


###### WAV RE-CREATION ######

sampleRate = w.getframerate() # hertz

obj = wave.open('sound.wav','w')
obj.setnchannels(w.getnchannels())
obj.setsampwidth(2)
obj.setframerate(sampleRate)
for i in range(0,len(flatten)):
   obj.writeframesraw(( flatten[i]).to_bytes(8,"big") )
obj.close()
```

Comment: I've got nothing to add to this as I know nothing; but this is definitely a nifty idea.

Comment: thanks @ewong , share an upvote if you like it! :)

Comment: png is a lossy format, so your reconstruction will sound nothing like the original

Comment: @FrenzyKiwi I’m not sure that’s correct, a quick Google search will show PNG is lossless

Comment: It’s tempting to go for something big, but I’d recommend testing this on a small snippet of audio. 64 16-bit samples will yield 256 bytes and a clean 16x16 pixel image. Print the values going in and coming out. Is there any correlation?

Comment: First problem I see is that you're treating `w.getnframes()` as if it meant the number of bytes in the decoded audio stream, but that would only be the case for 8bit mono. | The next thing is already wrong due to above, but If `w.getnframes()/3` is not a power of two, you will probably lose few more bytes due to rounding.

Answer (score 1):

You are introducing loss in your conversion to pixels.

First, you will lose one or two frames at the end with `for i in range(0,w.getnframes(),3):`, when the number of frames is not a multiple of three.

Second, your `dimensions = int(sqrt(w.getnframes()/3))` and then writing `dimensions` squared pixels will lose many frames when the number of frames divided by three is not a square.

Third, and most importantly, you are ignoring the sample width, as well as the number of channels. You are only saving the low eight bits of each sample in the image. If the sample width is 16 bits, you are essentially saving noise in the image.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry if this is a little late— thank you for your response. I am honored to be in the presence of an influential computer scientist!